# Long term engine issues by using Active Exhaust?

Tags: automotive-engineering

Looking to install OEM active valve mufflers on my 2019 Mustang EcoBoost.

Wondering if the valves opening and closing, thus changing exhaust back-pressure would cause the engine to run lean/rich and do long term harm to my bone stock car.

Long term reliability has priority over sound for me but if it has ZERO effect then I will go ahead and do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cross posted here: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/79429/10976

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OEM setup will be fine.  Ford will have different fueling maps set up for each setting.  Doing this without the electronics built in would be a mess but it's quite safe as long as the car knows what is going on with the exhaust.

Comment: Yes. But if I do this I would not be changing the fuel maps. I would only program the instrument panel cluster IPC module to allow control of the valve actuators and settings through the wiring harness. I don’t think the IPC has access to change fuel maps.

Comment: yeah that's not gonna work.  It needs to talk to the fuel computer.  I wouldn't do it.